# Unable to create a subclass's object in Swift's ViewController class

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

1. I create a swift class named 'Treasure.swift' and create a subclass of it inside the same file as follows:

   ```
   import Foundation

   class Treasure
   {
       let what: String
       let latitude: Double
       let longitude: Double

       init ( what: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
       {
           self.what = what
           self.latitude = latitude
           self.longitude = longitude
       }

       class HistoryTreasure: Treasure
       {
           let year: Int

           init(what: String, year: Int, latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
           {
               self.year = year
               super.init(what: what, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
           }
       }
   ```
2. Then I create a 'ViewController.swift' class and add the following code:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController
   {
       var treasures : [Treasure] = []

       override func viewDidLoad()
       {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           self.treasures = [HistoryTreasure()]
      }
    }
   ```
3. The issue is, I have created a property of ViewController class 'treasures' and declare it as array of 'Treasure' type. When I insert objects in above array like this: "`self.treasures = [Treasure(what: "hi", longitude: -37, latitude: 78),]`", it runs fine, But when I try to insert the object of type 'HistoryTreasure' (a subclass of 'Treasure') , then it shows we error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'HistoryTreasure'".
4. And also this 'ViewController' class was unable to identify the 'Historytreasure' class independently, i.e. can't able to import it. Please help me in understanding the above point.

Comment: I don't understand you issue, but whenever I've had problems with subclassing its because I didn't subclass NSObject. Its always good to subclass NSObject instead of nothing. That way, you get to the turtles.

Comment: This question has severe formatting issues.  Please take some time to get the formatting correct.  I can't tell if the issue is because `HistoryTreasure` is a nested class (accidentally) and thus you'd have to use `Treasure.HistoryTreasure` (or unnest) or if it just looks like a nested class.  There aren't enough closing brackets to your `Treasure.swift` file, so where ever you placed the right close bracket makes a huge impact on what the answer should be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has severe formatting issues. The formatting cannot be fixed without *some* guesswork, and that guesswork can significantly impact the understanding of the user's problem.

Comment: Indeed, please edit your question so we can tell what we're looking at. My guess is that you need to use syntax like `aHistoryTreasure as Treasure` to downcast to the base class, but I can't tell for sure what's going on.

Comment: First of all I am sorry for creating such a mess above, as I am new to stack overflow and Swift, will take care in future. And thanks @nhgrif for your suggestions, that's correct, I was creating a nested class and now able to use it as Treasure.HistoryTreasure. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Savy Did you INTEND to create a nested class?  I'm not sure that's the best approach here.

Comment: No @nhgrif, by mistake I done that as I am new to Swift coding, actually I want to create simple subclass of Treasure and want to insert the objects of HistoryTreasure (subclass) in the array ('self.treasures') of type Treasure (superclass) and implement the inheritance in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I found bugs in my above code with the help of @nhgrif's comment. First issue was by mistake, I was creating nested class 'HistoryTreasure' of 'Treasure' class. But I want to make a simple subclass (HistoryTreasure) of super class 'Treasure'. So I did the following alteration in my code (close the 'Treasure' class's curly braces before the start of 'HistoryTreasure' class):

   ```
   class Treasure : NSObject
   {
       let what: String
       let latitude: Double
       let longitude: Double

       init ( what: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
       {
           self.what = what
           self.latitude = latitude
           self.longitude = longitude
       }
   }

   class HistoryTreasure: Treasure
   {
        let year: Int

        init(what: String, year: Int, latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
        {
            self.year = year
            super.init(what: what, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        }
   }`
   ```
2. Now my code is running perfectly fine and able to generate and insert objects of subclass 'HistoryTreasure' in array of type 'Treasure' in ViewController class

`self.treasures = [HistoryTreasure(what: "hi", year: 1992, latitude: -37, longitude: 420)]`